# How to connect JDBC connectivity to Hbase using JMeter?

Tags: database, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

How to connect JDBC connectivity to Hbase using JMeter?

Please help here and share some links and drivers so that I can refer them.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you **really** want there is [Apache Phoenix](http://phoenix.incubator.apache.org/) project, given you have the driver under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you should be able to use `org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver` class and URL like `jdbc:phoenix:server1,server2:3333`

However it might be easier to go for Hadoop/HBase plugin which provides:

- [HBase Scan Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HBaseScanSampler/)
- [HBase Rowkey Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HBaseRowkeySampler/)
- and [HBase CRUD Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HBaseCRUDSampler/)

the plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

More information: [How to Load Test HBase with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-hbase-with-jmeter)